# mat-table is only displaying one value from the datasource

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngfor, angular-material-table

## Problem Statement Description

(1) I have a `mat-table` that receives input from a data source. (2) The data source receives data from the parent component which fetches the data from firebase through `ngOnChanges`, and also works with `ngOnInit`. Because I would need to modify the values later, `ngOnChanges` was my best course of action.

(3) Now, only one value from the data source is displayed. (4) Upon displaying the data of the data source on the front end through a JSON pipe, all the data displays. Which is an array of objects as seen

## Problem Statement Code Support

1. 

```
<table *ngIf="listColumnType?.isAccepted" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let columnSection of listColumnSectionsAccepted"  [matColumnDef]="columnSection?.title">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ columnSection?.title }}</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let entrepreneur">
            <span *ngIf="listColumnSectionsAccepted.indexOf(columnSection) < 3">
              <!-- entrepreneur['firstName'].... -->
              {{ entrepreneur[columnSection?.key]}}
            </span>

           <!-- Other Columns similar to the <span> tag above -->

          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="listColumnType?.isAccepted?fetchColumnTitles(listColumnSectionsAccepted):fetchColumnTitles(listColumnSectionsNotAccepted)"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: listColumnType?.isAccepted?fetchColumnTitles(listColumnSectionsAccepted):fetchColumnTitles(listColumnSectionsNotAccepted)"></tr>
      </table>
```

2. 

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes["entrepreneurList"]){
      this.entrepreneurList = changes["entrepreneurList"].currentValue
      // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.entrepreneurList)
      this.dataSource.data = this.entrepreneurList;
      // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      console.log(this.dataSource?.filteredData)
    }
  }
```

3.[image]

4. `{{ dataSource?.filteredData | json}}`
   [image]

## Observations

With static data everything displays as expected. The only thing I can't understand is why it only displays one of the items in the array if the data is fetched (only first item). What's even more bizzare is that with the json pipe, we can see all the data is in the dataSource.
Logging to console also shows that the data is present.

Comment: Did you try use dataSource?.filteredData as dataSource <table *ngIf="listColumnType?.isAccepted" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource.filteredData">

Comment: @NikitaBardakov yes I did. With 'datasource?filteredData' Still encountering the same issue :'(